# HTML input text field as wide as possible

Tags: html

I have a table with one row and two cells. I would like to get an input text field to be as wide as possible. How could do it that way?

```
(       0       )Text, text, text...
```

The main problem is that the width of the text input box is too much.

Here is the code:

```
<table style="width:400px">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px">
      (<input type="text" name="num" value="0" class="kentta" />)
    </td>

    <td style="width:200px">
      Text, text, text...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS code:

```
.kentta {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1px;
  border: none;

  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: did you try width: 100%;?

Comment: `style="border:none;text-align:center; width:100%"`

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of pixels, you can achieve it by using percentage of the width.

**As give below**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>                          This will grow as large as.
    <td style="width:80%"> <----'
      <input type="text" name="num" value="0" style="border:none;text-align:center" />
    </td>

    <td style="width:20%">
      Text, text, text...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. The main problem is that the width of the text input box is too much.

Answer (score 0):

It is maximum for any table data.Use this on browser on 100% width.

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   (<input type="text" name="num" value="0" style="border:none;text-align:center;width:98%;" />)
 </td>
 <td>
  Text, text, text...
 </td>
</tr>
```